# how do i get access to the label inside gridview/repeater

Tags: asp.net, gridview

as you can see in my code... i have  a label inside ItemTemplate and what i want is when i click on that particular control i would like to access to the label so that i can update the status...

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" OnItemCreated="Repeater1_ItemCreated" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    Book:
    <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <Mycontrol:Content1 ID="EmpControl" runat="server"   OnMyControlClick="EmpControl_clicking" />
    <br />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>


  protected void EmpControl_clicking(object sender, EmployeeEventArgs e)
    {
       // how do i get access to the lblStatus???
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the FindControl method to access controls within templates:

```
    protected void EmpControl_clicking(object sender, EmployeeEventArgs e)
    {
        MyControl myControl = (MyControl)sender;
        Label c = (Label)myControl.Parent.FindControl("lblStatus");
    }
```

Comment: my lblStatus is not inside MyControl its inside the ItemTemplate

Comment: The Parent property of myControl is the Item Template.

Comment: i see there is a small problem here...let say... i have 10 rows in my repeater and when i clicked on row 1 i able to get access to label and display the message which is great... let say if i click on row 2 i get the access to label and display the message but the row 1 message is still there, how can i clear the row 1 lblStatus? so in other words, display the message one at a anytime given

Comment: I am not sure I follow the new part to the question. Since the OnClick event is triggered for a specific MyControl from within the Item Template you will only have access to the controls within the current "instance" of the Item Template. You may want to update your question to be more specific on what you are trying to accomplish. Good luck.

Comment: I don't have the rights to comment on the new question, so I will do it here. Since you only want to show a single status at a time, you may think about pulling lblStatus out of the Repeater and add it directly to the WebForm.